# How to concatenate function to windows.onclick?

Tags: javascript

I have some component that do something in windows.onclick:

```
window.onclick = () => dosomething();
```

The problem is that if the component exists more than once, than it is override each other.

So what is the solution for that? How can i do something like

`window.onclick += () => dosomething();`

Comment: `onclick` can only be a single function.  If you want multiple, you need to use `addEventListener`.  Though this seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on...` accessor functions can only have one value assigned to them.

While you can do workarounds, the best option is to use `addEventListener` instead.

```
addEventListener("click", () => dosomething());
addEventListener("click", () => dosomethingelse());
```

If you really want to do a work around (and ick) then you could do something like:

```
window.onclick = () => dosomething();
window.onclick = (function () {
    const old = window.onclick;
    return (e) => {
        old(e);
        dosomethingelse();
    };
})();
```

… where you copy the old function to a new variable, and then create a new function which calls both functions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a click listener to `document` and not directly to `window`. But attaching more than one handler is done by:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => doSomething());
```

But even though `Window` is also an `EventTarget` so technically you can do the same with it, but I would recommend doing the same on `document` instead.